# Web Applet Fails to Launch using Java 7 Mac OS X 10.8 due to whitespace in path name

Tags: java, macos, path, applet

I'm trying to launch a web applet (Cisco UCS Manager 2.1) on a Mac running OS X 10.8.4 and Java 7 Update 21.  The UCS Manager applet runs another applet (a console, in this case) and that is what's failing.  I have reported the bug, but I need a workaround if possible in the meantime.

The problem is that the JavaAppletPlugin is located in "/Library/Internet Plug-Ins" and the whitespace in the path is causing the issue.  Is there a way to change the plugin path?  Or just reassign it in Java and use symbolic links?

Comment: What is the HTML used to launch the applet?

Comment: I'm not certain how to get the HTML without the source.  I don't see it in the console or system logs.  I do know the path it's trying to parse is "/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin"

Comment: *"I'm not certain how to get the HTML without the source."*  That does not make any sense to me.  If you use FF, got to Tools | Web Developer | Page Source.  The thing is, I want to see the actual applet call in HTML, just as the browser sees it.

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood what you were asking for.  The UCS Manager applet launches with no problem.  The HTML used to launch the applet is: https://ucsm.example.com/ucsm/ucsm.jnlp and after I load that, I click on a button to launch a console for a server blade.  It's that button within the applet that is failing.

Comment: That URL is a 404 here.  But copy/paste the text of it into the question.  I am trying to figure out exactly where that `"/Library/Internet Plug-Ins"` path comes from.  It is likely an easy fix once identified.

Comment: Sorry for disappearing, unforeseen travel (ugh).  I can't give you the real URL unfortunately, it only works on the internal network.  That path is given to the applet by Java on OS X.  From what I can find out, it's where Apple chose to put the JavaAppletPlugin when Apple had control of Java on OS X.  It looks like Oracle kept the path for legacy reasons.

Answer (score 0):

Try escaping the space with a backslash ie `"/Library/Internet\ Plug-Ins"`. I know this works for .jnlp files, so it may work in this case as well.